# Corosync/Pacemaker pcs equivalent commands to crm

Tags: pacemaker, corosync

I know **crm** utility command has been people's preferred method to manage clusters when it comes to High Availability with corosync & pacemaker. Now, its been deprecated and we are told to work with **pcs** utility commands which suppose to do all sort of things that we used to do with **crm**.

Now what I am troubling with is to find the pcs equivalent command to;

`crm node attribute <node_name> set <resource_name> <some_parameters>`.

If I try with pcs node, there is no any such command set available.

I am at CentOS 7.2 version & working with Percona master-slave cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure? I have it in PCS version 0.9.158 (CentOS 7.4):

```
# pcs node attribute --help

Usage: pcs node <command>
    attribute [[<node>] [--name <name>] | <node> <name>=<value> ...]
        Manage node attributes.  If no parameters are specified, show attributes
        of all nodes.  If one parameter is specified, show attributes
        of specified node.  If --name is specified, show specified attribute's
        value from all nodes.  If more parameters are specified, set attributes
        of specified node.  Attributes can be removed by setting an attribute
        without a value.
```

Also, `crmsh` isn't deprecated. It's still an active project: https://github.com/ClusterLabs/crmsh

Comment: Thanks for looking into this from your valuable time. Yes, that was my bad as I did not check the updated version. Mine had pcs version 0.9.143. But when I update it to 0.9.158, it works.